# reading data from sqlite database and adding to list view through hashmap

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

i want to read the 'empname' and 'place' from sqlite database and list into a listview
i tried the given code, but the code shows error like 'unreachable code' can any one help me to find out the problem.

```
 public void listEmps()
{
    this.myList.clear();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //HashMap map = new HashMap();

    Cursor cursor = this.dbAdapter.ListEmp();
    int i;
    if((cursor !=null)&&(cursor.getCount()>0))
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        i=0;
        if(i>cursor.getCount())
        {
            cursor.close();
            myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.listadapter, new String[]{"name","place"},
                    new int[]{R.id.textViewName,R.id.textViewPlace});
             this.lvEmp.setAdapter(myAdapter);
             this.myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
    while(true)
    {
        return;

        map.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("EmpName")));
        map.put("place", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("place")));
        this.myList.add(map);
         map = new HashMap();
          if (!cursor.isLast())
              cursor.moveToNext();
          i++;
          break;
          cursor.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `do->while` like this:

```
     public void listEmps()
{


  this.myList.clear();
    //HashMap map = new HashMap();

    Cursor cursor = this.dbAdapter.ListEmp();

if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("EmpName")));
                        map.put("place", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("place")));
                        this.myList.add(map);

                    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                 cursor.close();
        myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.listadapter, new String[]{"name","place"},
                new int[]{R.id.textViewName,R.id.textViewPlace});
         this.lvEmp.setAdapter(myAdapter);
         this.myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

your code is unreachable becouse of that code snippet:

```
while(true)
{
    return;
```

that means all of the code behind that line is not reachable...
First of all remove the

```
return;
```

Furthermore IMO it is a very bad practice declaring endless loops with `while(true)`.
Remove that too and try it with:

```
while (!cursor.isLast())
```

another place for unreachable code is:

```
break;
cursor.close();
```

with the `break;` you will leave the process. `cursor.close();` cant never be reached.

Comment: i had given the return at the end of while loop. still problem exist.. how to resolve it?